# How to use a value not in the scope of a function?

Tags: r, global-variables

How to access variables defined outside the scope of a function.

```
foo <- "bar"

f <- function(){
  print(foo)
}
```

I should be able to print "bar"

Comment: You can. Did you try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `get()`:

```
foo <- "bar"

test <- function(){
  print(get("foo", envir = .GlobalEnv))
}

> test()
[1] "bar"
```

Comment: `get` is not necessary here. But it adds some safety, because it makes it explicit where the value should be searched for.

Answer (score 3):

Your code works as written:

```
foo <- "bar"

f <- function(){
  print(foo)
}

f()
#[1] "bar"
```

Of course, it's not good practice to rely on scoping. You should instead pass variables as function parameters.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't even think of executing the code as written :)